# Joining using an OR operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables. An Employee key table, and a table containing their Work Location.

```
EMPID   EMPNAME
1234    James
9876    Kevin
4567    Elaine

EMPID   EMPID_OLD   LOCATION
1234                TORONTO
987610  9876        NEW YORK
4567    104567      CHICAGO
```

The problem is that the employee key in the second table isn't consistent, and is scattered between the EMPID and EMPID_OLD columns.

I've written a query that involves the "or" operator in the LEFT JOIN expression.:

```
select empid, location
from emp m1 
left join emp_location m2
    on m2.empid = m1.empid OR m2.empid_old = m1.empid
```

This query theoretically works, however it takes about 45 minutes to run. If I remove the "OR" expression, it takes only 5 seconds to run.

A `COALESCE` expression cannot be used, because the first value it matches, may not be accurate, therefore it has join on either value it can find a match on, not necessarily the first one.

Is there any way I can optimize this query, without having to separate the joins, as I've done below?

This an oversimplified version of a huge query I'm working on, so obviously trying to avoid multiple joins for the same table.

```
select m1.empid, coalesce(m2.location,m3.location)
from emp m1 
left join emp_location m2
    on m2.empid = m1.empid 
left join emp_location m3
    on m3.empid_old = m1.empid
```

Comment: Your last version is the way to improve performance.

Comment: " If I remove the "OR" expression, it takes only 5 seconds to run." for both empid  & empid_old?

Comment: Is `emp_location` indexed on both `empid` and `empid_old`? Are duplicate results possible or desirable? `select e.empid, el.location from emp as e inner join emp_location as el on el.empid = e.empid union all select e.empid, el.location from emp as e inner join emp_location as el on el.empid_old = e.empid;` may produce duplicates. Changing it to `union` removes duplicates at the expense of a sort.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve the issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

Two left joins is the way to go here. If COALESCE does not do the trick for you, then you can use a case when condition to determine which location to use:

```
select m1.empid, 
       case when m2.location = 'Condition for location accuracy' then m2.location
            else m3.location end as location
from emp m1 
left join emp_location m2 on m2.empid= m1.empid 
left join emp_location m3 on m3.empid_old= m1.empid
```

Answer (score 0):

Joins and that too left join or right join or cartesian are however costly.

Have an index on columns `( EMPID, EMPID_OLD)` in the second table as conditioning on the two columns have been done in your join condition via `OR`. This could help to certain extent

Answer (score 0):

Often a `union all` performs better in such circumstances as SQL Server can optimise each join independently e.g.

```
select m1.empid, m2.[location]
from emp m1 
left join emp_location m2 on m2.empid = m1.empid 

union all

select m1.empid, m3.[location]
from emp m1 
left join emp_location m3  on m3.empid_old = m1.empid
```